# drawstring restringing system

Tags: patentability, design, cost

I am an engineering student trying to contact the owners contact information in order to ask them a few questions regarding their design I was wondering if I could receive a phone number or email to reach out to them?

Comment: Are you referring to a patent? If so you need to provide the patent number for us to help you.

Comment: This is a site for the public to ask and answer question about patents - we are not the patent office or a direct way to contact the inventors or owners. You may have reached the site via a link on google patents related to a particular patent. The information about what patent that might have been did not make it though to your post in any way that is visible.

Answer (score 1):

For a US patent issued in the last few decades you can look it up in [Public PAIR](https://portal.uspto.gov/pair/PublicPair). It has a non-user friendly interface to initially look up an application's history. Within that public record you can find the name and contact information for the patent attorney or agent if they used one. Also in the file wrapper tab you will find all of the documents filed in the case by the applicant and the examiner. One document called an ADS in that record will have some address information for the inventors and applicant.

If the application was assigned to a third party *during its prosecution*, that should also be reflected in a document in the file wrapper. There might also be a record of an assignment  in the [USPTO Redecoration database](https://www.uspto.gov/patents/maintain/patents-assignments-change-search-ownership). However, there is no requirement that an assignment be recorded.